# \footnote and \starttextbackground interaction?

Tags: footnotes, context, backgrounds

When a `\footnote` is placed such that there is a `\starttextbackground` frame split across the page break, the text backgound w/frame is being applied to the footnote as well. Am I doing something wrong, or did I find a bug?

MWE:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\starttext 

\input lorem.tex

Why is all the rum\footnote{A beverage treasured by pirates.} gone?

\starttextbackground
\input lorem.tex
\stoptextbackground

\stoptext
```

produces... [image]

Comment: Add `\setconstant\kindofpagetextareas\plusone` to your document to change the default bahviour of text backgrounds.

Comment: That's more an answer than a comment. BTW, where does one find these things documented, short of reading the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To exclude the footnote area from the background of the `textbackground` environment you have to change the value of the `\kindofpagetextareas` constant.

The default value for the register is 2 which applies the background at the end of a page also to the footnote area while the value 1 ends the background at the page break of text.

```
\setuptextbackground
  [location=paragraph]

\setconstant\kindofpagetextareas\plusone

\starttext 

\input lorem

Why is all the rum\footnote{A beverage treasured by pirates.} gone?

\starttextbackground
\input lorem
\stoptextbackground

\stoptext
```

Comment: \kindofpagetextareas is not in wiki.contextgarden.net ... where is it documented?

Comment: @ScottLovell The command is mentioned only the mailing list but you can add the information to the wiki.